# How to get Godot lighting to not affect node

Tags: godot, godot4

In my Godot project I have two light sources. One will be a players flashlight which will be able to illuminate anything and the other light will be ambient light that will illuminate everything except for enemy players.

I have the ambient light on cull mask 1 and layer 1. I have the enemy player mesh set to layer 2. The ambient light doesn't illuminate the enemy player but you can't see the ground under the enemy player (So it's very obvious where the enemy is even if you can't see them).

How do I make the enemy player invisible when hit with ambient light?